# Sideloading with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, sideloading

I'm attempting to get rid of some async relationships in Ember-Data and sideload them instead but am running into some issues.

My API sends back the related data but the records are properties on each object returned instead of a separate array/object on the root. I'm using `extractArray` to munge the data so ED likes it but can't quite get it right. Here is a sample of the data returned from the API:

```
{
  "record": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "3M Aerospace",
      "currency": 6,
      "paymentTerms": 3,
      "Currencies_by_currency": {
        "id": 6,
        "currency": "USD",
        "description": "US Dollar",
        "sortOrder": 1
      },
      "PaymentTerms_by_paymentTerms": {
        "id": 3,
        "term": "NET10",
        "description": "Due with 10 days of invoice date"
        "sortOrder": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "BAE Aerospace",
      "currency": 6,
      "paymentTerms": 3,
      "Currencies_by_currency": {
        "id": 6,
        "currency": "USD",
        "description": "US Dollar"
        "sortOrder": 1
      },
      "PaymentTerms_by_paymentTerms": {
        "id": 3,
        "term": "NET10",
        "description": "Due with 10 days of invoice date"
        "sortOrder": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I know I need to get `Countries_by_mailingAddressCountry`, `Currencies_by_currency`, and `PaymentTerms_by_paymentTerms` out of the object root. Where exactly are they supposed to go? I thought it should be:

```
{
    "record": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            // other data...
            "currency": 6,
            "paymentTerms": 3,
            // more data...
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            // other data...
            "currency": 6,
            "paymentTerms": 3,
            // more data...
        }
    ],
    "currencies": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "currency": "USD",
            "description": "US Dollar",
            "sortOrder": 1
        }
    ],
    "paymentTerms": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "term": "NET10",
            "description": "Due with 10 days of invoice date",
            "isActive": true,
            "sortOrder": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

but ED complains that it can't find the related data. The models are defined as

```
App.Vendor = DS.Model.extend(App.Addressable, {
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    currency: DS.belongsTo('currency'),
    paymentTerms: Ds.belongsTo('payment-term')
});

App.Currency = DS.Model.extend({
    currency: string,
    description: string,
    sortOrder: number,
});

App.PaymentTerm = DS.Model.extend({
    term: string,
    description: string,
    sortOrder: number,
});
```

Comment: Is `"record"` supposed to be `"vendors"` in your JSON output ?

Comment: yep that was it. Figured it out after posting. I was circling back around to update this issue with the proper formatting. I did have to refactor a large part of my adapter to get sideloading working properly.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I had to reformat my json to the following format

```
{
    "vendors": [
        // vendor objects
    ],
    "currencies": [
        // currency objects
    ],
    "paymentTerms": [
        // paymentTerms objects
    ]
}
```

Once I had this formatted correctly and refactored my adapter everything was gravy!